# GROUP BY with only first row of sequence of one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

at first here is the alpha version of what I want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45c89/2

However I don't want to count all representative_id, but only this rows with the lowest id, eg:

```
(`id`, `economy_id`, `representative_id`)
(1, 1, 5), <-this one, lowest id through the same economy_id=1
(2, 1, 6),
(3, 1, 7),
(4, 1, 8),
(5, 1, 3),
(6, 1, 4),
(7, 1, 1),
(8, 1, 2),
(9, 1, 102),
(10, 2, 7), <-this one, lowest id through the same economy_id=2
(11, 2, 8),
(12, 2, 102),
(13, 2, 1),
(14, 2, 2),
(15, 2, 3),
(16, 2, 4),
(17, 3, 3), <-this one, lowest id through the same economy_id=3
(18, 3, 4),
(19, 3, 1),
(20, 3, 2),
(21, 3, 102),
(22, 4, 1), <-this one, lowest id through the same economy_id=4
(23, 4, 2),
(24, 4, 102),
(25, 5, 1),  <-this one, lowest id through the same economy_id=5
(26, 5, 2),
(27, 5, 102),
(28, 5, 7),
(29, 6, 1),  <-this one, lowest id through the same economy_id=6
```

The output should be:

representative_id, count()

According to above example:

```
5, 1
7, 1
3, 1
1, 3
```

Is it possible only in SQL?

Comment: I don't understand the count

Comment: @Strawberry Hi Strawberry :D Thx you are here :) Which count?

Comment: Someone updated my post, but now is incorrect. How to turn it back? @Strawberry this Count means How many times representative_id occures as the first record (lowest id) in a sequence of the same economy_id

Comment: I updated - I thought I was making it clearer! :-(

Comment: I've changed it back :) It's not obvious problem

Comment: It's OK - I think I get it now...

Comment: If I'm not missing anything may be this is what you are looking for: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45c89/31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think this should work using `min` in a `subquery` and joining back to itself:

```
select s.representative_id, count(*)
from stl_parliament s
  join 
  (
    select min(id) minid
    from stl_parliament
    group by economy_id
  ) t on s.id = t.minid
group by s.representative_id
```

- [Updated Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45c89/30)

Comment: Awesome! Is it possible to add in the output apart form this special count you made, ordinary general count, so representative_id, general_count, this_subquery_count? Or is it better to do it in separate query?

Comment: @RobM -- wonderful, wasn't 100% sure what you needed, but glad this worked!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT x.representative_id
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM stl_parliament x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT economy_id
            , MIN(id) min_id 
         FROM stl_parliament
        GROUP
           BY economy_id
     ) y
    ON y.economy_id = x.economy_id 
   AND y.min_id = x.id
 GROUP 
    BY representative_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45c89/34

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit confusing.
is it what do you want?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a58c7/19

```
select count(economy_id), min_rep_id
from 
(
SELECT economy_id, min(representative_id) as min_rep_id
from stl_parliament
GROUP BY economy_id
) as x
GROUP BY min_rep_id
```

Answer (score 0):

A little complex but should work :

```
select m.col1, m.col2, count(m.col2) from (
select t.economy_id as col1, l.representative_id as col2 from stl_parliament l,
(select economy_id,MIN(id) as minid from stl_parliament GROUP BY economy_id) t
where t.economy_id=l.economy_id and t.minid=l.id) m group by m.col2
```

Lots of subqueries, I am not so good with joins

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query.

```
SELECT a.rep_id,count(a.rep_id) 
FROM(Select min(id) as mid,representative_id as rep_id,economy_id 
FROM stl_parliament 
GROUP BY economy_id) as a
GROUP BY a.rep_id
```